# Get parent page on creating new Wagtail Page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I need to change some field default value given a value from the parent page when creating a new page. When editing an existing page, this is not a problem, but when creating a new page, I need to set a default value for a field. I have tried overriding the admin form, on init for WagtailAdminPageForm, the parent_page parameter is empty. And if I try to do it on the init method form Page subclass, there is no arg or kwargs with the parent information.

is there a way to get the page for which the new page will be the parent?

This is what I tried on Page constructor

```
class CMSPage(Page):
    .
    .
    .
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseContentMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if hasattr(self.get_parent().specific, 'published_site') and self.get_parent().specific.published_site == 'extranet':
            self.published_site = 'extranet'
```

This works editing a page, for new page, I get that NoneType objects has no attribute specific.

Django version is 1.10, Python version is 3.6, Wagtail version is 1.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After clarification of the question, here is a second answer that might be more suitable. Note that this **requires Wagtail 1.11.x** which as at this time is not yet released.

## Example Code for Solution

**First** Create a new class for your custom page form, usually in models.py or wherever the model for your page is.

```
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm

class MyCustomPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    # Override the __init__ function to update 'initial' form values
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, parent_page=None, *args, **kwargs):
        print('parent_page', parent_page, parent_page.id, parent_page.title)
        # update the kwargs BEFORE the init of the super form class
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if not instance.id:
            # only update the initial value when creating a new page
            kwargs.update(initial={
                # 'field': 'value'
                'title': parent_page.id  # can be anything from the parent page
            })
        # Ensure you call the super class __init__
        super(MyCustomPageForm, self).__init__(data, files, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent_page = parent_page
```

**Second** On the page model definition, tell that model to use the form class you have defined

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page

class MyCustomPage(Page):
    base_form_class = MyCustomPageForm
```

## Explanation of Solution

- Wagtail provides the ability to override the form class (note: not model class) that gets called when building the form for creation and editing in Wagtail Admin.
- Documentation: [Customising generated forms](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms.WagtailAdminPageForm)
- Our custom form class will inherit the `WagtailAdminPageForm` class.
- Inside this new form class, we want to define our own `__init__` function, this is called when the form is created.
- Note the Github code for the [default definition of `__init__` on WagtailAdminPageForm](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailadmin/forms.py#L320)
- To inject custom values, we will override the `initial` data in `kwargs` before the calling of the class' super `__init__`
- We only want to do this when a new page is being created, so check that the instance has no `id`
- We can access the `parent_page` instance and any fields in it
- After adding our custom initial data, then we call the super `__init__` with the changed kwargs
- Note: The reason for the requirement of Wagtail 1.11.x is that previous versions until that point did not add parent_page when calling the class model until [pull request 3508](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/3508)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the Wagtail Hooks:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/reference/hooks.html

Here is a basic example that works (in the Wagtaildemo app), in this example, I am just getting the parent page's title. It should work the same if you are getting something else from the parent's page specific model. Note that this updates the record **after** it has been created, not as part of the creation itself.

```
# my_app/wagtail_hooks.py
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore import hooks


@hooks.register('after_create_page')
def do_after_page_create(request, page):
    # get the parent page from the current page
    parent = page.get_parent().specific
    # get the value from the parent page
    parent_title = parent.title
    # get a new instance of the page that was just created
    new_page = Page.objects.get(id=page.id).specific
    # update the value in the page that was just created & save
    new_page.parent_title = parent_title
    new_page.save()
```

I have used the Wagtail hooks a lot and they work well, you could further refine this by checking the `new_page.content_type == "CMSPage"` to ensure this only updates pages of that specific model.

Finally, it might be good to look into how Wagtail sites works, this might be a more specific solution to your issue in the example code. You can add extra [settings to your Site Model](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/reference/contrib/settings.html) and have [multiple Sites in Wagtail](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/reference/pages/model_reference.html#site). I am not sure if your example was just a rough example or the exact issue you are facing.

Comment: @Ib ben johnston thanks for your answer, however, what I want to achieve is to change a default value for a form field, depending on certain property from the parent page. Not updating the page after is saved. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Cheluis does this explain your use case better? Just trying to understand. 1. User loads a form page (to fill out the form). 2. Default field value (eg. a dropdown box), would normally be set to the first value on the list. 3. Override behaviour is to set the value based on the Form's parent page. Note: I have overridden default form values before (based on URL query vars), so I can probably suggest a way to do this.

Comment: No, my case is when you are adding a new page which is a child of another page, I want to catch it parent on its create form, not after its created. I need to set a value on Create form depending on a parents field value

Comment: @Cheluis Looks like you had also flagged a similar issue that I came cross in the wagtail codebase, and it appears that a fix is in the latest 1.11 release which should come out really soon. I have created a new answer as the original might still be of use to some people. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Ib ben Johnston, yeah I tried your approach but for that very same reason, I couldn't get the parent page instance. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problems. Also, the 1.11 release is now out, http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11/releases/1.11.html